# How can I get X Axis Label value

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

*react with react-chart-js*

I want to get X-Axis Label Value and format after rendering on canvas,
I currently use this callback function, but I only get the X-Axis Label index value,
I want to get text value,

[This is my code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkyyt.png)

[This is my devtools to show the X-Axis labels console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxdgb.png)

[This is a project screenshot with my X-Axis Label text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPXZZ.png)

how can I get X Axis text value?

12/28 updated:

- [callback function in X-Axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HGhU.png)
- [console.log X-Axis (value, index, ticks)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDjRQ.png)

Comment: Have a look to the doc where callback option can have 3 arguments: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats, the third arg is the array of ticks and using the index you can get the value.

Comment: @user2057925 Hi, I watched the doc issue, I think this callback is used for Y-Axis,
I try to console.log about X-Axis (value, index, ticks), and it returns [index number, index number, object]
I update my issue about this function screenshot

Comment: Can you add a codepen in order to have a look?